# Android Send custom intent from bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I don't even know if this is possible, but I'd like to send a custom intent action from a Bluetooth device, capture it with a receiver in my application and trigger some logic. The bluetooth manufacturer has told us that he can integrate any data in the payload, so maybe if he creates the intent action there?

I repeat, I don't know if there's any way to achieve this, so any answer will be welcome. Thanks in advance.